# Как заставить контур крутиться вокруг своей оси?

Tags: html, css, анимация

```css
.main-ball {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
  margin: 200px;
}

.main-ball:after {
  content: '';
  border: 4px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(75deg) rotateY(0);
  top: -70px;
  left: -70px;
  animation: anim 5s ease infinite;
  
  
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(75deg) rotateY(0);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(70deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(75deg) rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-ball">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вокруг какой именно оси, то вам стоит использовать значение `rotateZ` для анимации.

```css
.main-ball {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
  margin: 200px;
}

.main-ball:after {
  content: '';
  border: 4px solid blue;
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(75deg) rotateZ(0);
  top: -70px;
  left: -70px;
  animation: anim 5s linear infinite;
  
  
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(75deg) rotateZ(0);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(70deg) rotateZ(180deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(75deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-ball">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Опередили. Почти ответил, но застопорился на визуализации однотонной окружности - вращения же не видно было бы! С жёлтеньким сектором хорошо придумано. Похоже, что мне тоже проще надо подходить))